# transfer files from Mac to nexus 7 via bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer, nexus-7

I forgot the USB cable and I have some files on the Mac that I would like to transfer to my nexus 7. Is it possible to do this via bluetooth? Is there an app that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Provided both the Android handset and your Mac share a common wifi connection (same AP that allows client-to-client connections):

Install an FTP server or a webserver app that allows uploading:

For example [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid). It allows file-uploading via drag&drop even. You'll find your uploaded files in airdroid/upload in the SDcard folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Bluetooth, but try my Open Source project [cross copy](http://cross-copy.net) for inter-device copy and paste:

1. browse to http://cross-copy.net on both devices
2. choose the same code word to establish a connection between the devices
3. upload the files on the Mac
4. a download link for each file will appear on the page of the Nexus 7